# Using intent share text with multiple image in android

Tags: java, android

HI can anyone please help me i am trying to share text with multiple image but i am getting this error **Key android.intent.extra.TEXT expected ArrayList but value was a java.lang.String. The default value  was returned.**
Here is my code-

```
    String text = "Share text.";
    Uri pictureUri =  getLocalBitmapUri(shareImg_imvw);
    uriList.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    uriList.add(pictureUri);
    }
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.setType("*/*");
    //        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    // new code
    ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
    extra_text.add(text);
    shareIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.send_intent_title)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` support *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`. Apps do not have to support both. Do not expect both to be used by all apps.

Second, `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` requires that `EXTRA_TEXT` *and* `EXTRA_STREAM` be `ArrayList` extras. Replace `putExtra()` with `putStringArrayListExtra()`, passing in an `ArrayList<String>` of the multiple strings that you want to share.

Comment: That's means you are telling their is no way to share multiple image with text???

Comment: When i am passing this `putStringArrayListExtra()` that time error has gone but text is not shearing.

Comment: @Subho: As I wrote, apps do not have to support both text and streams with `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. You may have a bit better luck if you make both `ArrayLists` be the same length. Since your `uriList` has 5 `Uri` values in it, put 5 copies of your string in `extra_text`. But, again, do not expect all apps (or even any apps) to use both the text and the streams.

Comment: Not a single app is working 

`ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            uriList.add(pictureUri);
            extra_text.add(text);
        }`

Text is not shearing with the image..

Comment: @Subho: Temporarily comment out your `shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);` line and see what happens. If your text starts showing up now, you know that the apps that you are testing will only use one or the other extra.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, those app i have in my phone not a single one support multiple text that is why text is not coming with multiple image :)

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing how to retrive multiple image from other app like gallery app(Moto g3) . This is my menifest intent... 
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />`

My app is only coming when mre than two image is selected.

Comment: @Subho: Whatever app you are testing presumably only uses `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` when some threshold is reached.

Comment: Ya I got the solution i put two intent-filter just like this way

`<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>`

In this your app will coming if you select one or more than one image.